# How to replace the deprecated function `QWheelEvent::delta()` in the zoom in / zoom out function?

Tags: c++, qt

I was using the `delta()` function from the `QWheelEvent` class to achieve the zoom in, zoom out. now it is **deprecated**, and they advise in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent-obsolete.html#delta) to use `pixelDelta()` or `angleDelta()` instead, but they are `QPoint` objects!

can anybody please tell me how to replace this deprecated function with another ones?

```
void MapView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    if(event->delta()>0)
    {
        if(m_scale < MAX_SCALE)
        {
            std::cout << m_scale << std::endl;
            this->scale(ZOOM_STEP, ZOOM_STEP);
            m_scale *= ZOOM_STEP;
        }
    }
    else if(event->delta() < 0)
    {
        if(m_scale >= MIN_SCALE)
        {
            std::cout << m_scale << std::endl;
            this->scale(1/ZOOM_STEP, 1/ZOOM_STEP);
            m_scale *= 1/ZOOM_STEP;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use `angleDelta().y()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation of `angleDelta`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html#angleDelta) says that `angleDelta().y()` will return the angle by which the *vertical* mouse wheel was rotated and `angleDelta().x()` will return the angle by which the *horizontal* mouse wheel was rotated.

For zooming I'm assuming you will want to use vertical scrolling, so changing the conditions accordingly gives:

```
void MapView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    if(event->angleDelta().y() > 0)
    {
        if(m_scale < MAX_SCALE)
        {
            std::cout << m_scale << std::endl;
            this->scale(ZOOM_STEP, ZOOM_STEP);
            m_scale *= ZOOM_STEP;
        }
    }
    else if(event->angleDelta().y() < 0)
    {
        if(m_scale >= MIN_SCALE)
        {
            std::cout << m_scale << std::endl;
            this->scale(1/ZOOM_STEP, 1/ZOOM_STEP);
            m_scale *= 1/ZOOM_STEP;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NB Qt docs clarify the horizontal/vertical `QPoint` structure **5.15**, but if you're like me and are using, say, 5.9 they [do not](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/qwheelevent.html#angleDelta) (5.12 has the same doc. issue).  So if you're, say, using CentOS 7 and Qt Creator's local help docs you're not crazy and you didn't miss something obvious.